# How do I receive all ipv6 multicast packets using a raw socket?

Tags: linux, sockets, ipv6, multicast

I am trying to write a application for Linux that will route/forward ipv6 multicast packets. To do this I am trying to open a ipv6 raw socket that will receive all multicast packets from all interfaces. I can then inspect the packet and possibly forward it on another interface.

I haven't found any combination of raw socket options that will let me do this. Is it possible?

Comment: You could look into the source code of the [mrd6 IPv6 multicast routing daemon](https://github.com/hugosantos/mrd6), which should also be available in most Linux distributions.

Comment: Your problem is that the host is not subscribing to multicast packets, you actually are receiving everything sent to the host.